A movie about 2 women during WW2
In 2015 I was switching channels and I saw this movie I was never able to find again. This is what I remember:

It's an European movie, i don't know the exact spoken language but
i'm sure it wasn't English/Spanish/Italian since i can understand
those but i couldn't understand this movie.
It's possible that it's a made-for-TV-movie.
There are no known actors at least no one from Hollywood. I think the movie is from the 2000's+

PLOT:
The movie is about 2 civilian women during WW2, one is a blonde and the other has dark hair. They are in some occupied European country.
They are forced to work making shells on a Nazi controlled factory, they have to do this with insane speed and precision. They are constantly being yelled at my SS generals, but there is one of them who treats them well (probably in love or compassion). I think some kind of accident happens in the factory a shell explodes at some point, they get transferred elsewhere.
Another scene I remember: They get to a place where the German keep kids and babies. Initially, they are happy to be there because at least they don't have to handle bombs with their hands however things get ugly again when the blonde gets forced to have sex with SS generals to give birth to perfectly pure Aryan babies. The dark hair woman isn't perfect enough so they leave her alone.
I don't know if they manage to escape or not, that's what I remember but I'd like to see it again. Sounds like an interesting movie. I doubt anyone knows it but you never know!
When I searched I found one about lesbians but I don't remember these women being lesbians. It's definitely not that one.

"I don't think that's my movie!" -If you are unable to look at a movie and determine that it isn't your movie, then this question should be closed.

It's a polite way of saying No. If i see the movie i'm looking for i'll know.

Fair enough. That much wasn't immediately obvious to me. Best not to leave such things ambiguous and open to interpretation.

@GhotiandChips fixed! Thanks!

This is a longshot and I'm not 100% sure this is your movie, but depending on how well you remember it, there is chance it might be: Les femmes de l'ombre (2008).

In 1944, in London, Lieutenant Pierre Desfontaines assigns his sister Louise Desfontaines to convince three other women to form a five-woman task force under his command to rescue a British geologist from a German hospital in the countryside. The geologist was assigned by Colonel Maurice Buckmaster in a reconnaissance mission of the soil of the beaches at Normandy for the D-Day and had been captured by the Germans. Louise and Pierre force the prostitute Jeanne Faussier that is imprisoned for murdering her pimp; the explosives expert Gaëlle Lemenech that misses action; and the former dancer and fiancé of Colonel Karl Heindrich, Suzy Desprez, using blackmail and unethical methods to fly to France and join the Italian agent Maria Luzzato in the assignment.
They are well-succeeded but when they deliver the geologist to the British aeroplane, Pierre betrays the group. He forces the women to travel to Paris to kill Colonel Heindrich who suspects that the landing of the allied forces will be through Normandy, in a dangerous mission.

As I said, I can't be certain, since there are at least 5 different women in this movie, there are few points I find that may connect. I marked a few of them above.
So, if your memory of the movie is impeccable, this is surely not the the one you are looking for. However, if not, there are surely some things that may connect. For instance, the different places they worked might be part of the mission, since they have an explosive expert which could explain that one part and they have a prostitute expert in seducing men. This could explain all the places they've passed, the main cast is all composed by women, the movie is french, and released after 2000.

If it is not the one, I'll gladly delete it.

I've been looking at every scene of this movie (admittedly skipping). And i can say it's not it (it missed the scenes i remember). The movie i remember was around these 2 women (friends), they seemed pretty much civilians on an nazi occupied EU country. But damn you got pretty close, i've been looking at the list of ww2 films and couldn't find it myself. I think i will delete the question cos now i'm second guessing the language or country of origin....i know it wasn't eng/spa/ita but might as well be Czech, polish or other lang i can't understand! so yeah...might as well give up.

@MichaelRogers Don't give up so easily :) You could edit your question to express your uncertainty about the language and leave it open. Maybe someone finds the answer later on.

@Marzipanherz Ok you are right let's just leave it here maybe someone knows this movie before i die. =D

@MichaelRogers Oh, no worries. I'll give another look. But it would be a lot easier if you could narrow down the language.

I really thought it was french, but now i'm scared i remember it wrong and have people disregarding other movies that could be the right one because of the language difference.
